# <p> tags wrapping my text, but no where in content or code

Tags: java, android, html

On my Article view, my byline is appearing with `<p></p>` tags around it.

I'm importing my data from an online XML file, inserting into the database, then displaying it.  There are no paragraph tags in the XML or in the database, and my code (as you can see below) doesn't have paragraph tags in it either.

What is happening?  Why are they appearing and how to I get rid of them?

**Code:**

```
//ArticlesDataSource.java
article.byline = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeXml(
    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Article.COLUMN_BYLINE)));
article.byline = article.byline.toUpperCase();

//ArticleActivity.java
TextView articleBylineView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.articleByline);

articleBylineView.setText(article.byline);

if((article.byline.length() == 0) || article.byline == null) {
    articleBylineView.setVisibility(View.GONE); }

//article.xml
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/articleByline"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/articleByline"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:textSize="9dp"
    android:textColor="@color/light_gray"/>
```

**Example:**

XML data:

```
<![CDATA[ By JohnDoe  Noo York Times ]]>
```

Database data (SQlite):

```
By John Doe  The Noo York Times
```

What is displayed:

```
<P>BY JOHN DOE  THE NOO YORK TIMES</P>
```

Comment: Isn't that a question for whoever wrote `StringEscapeUtils`? There is no such class in Android.

Comment: CommonsWare - it's not.  Even if I remove that, it still has the paragraph tags.

Comment: And when you set a breakpoint, or used `Log.d()`, to dump `article.byline`, before you called `setText()`, what did it have?

Comment: It shows the P tags in a Log.d() just before the setText.

Comment: Hence, you need to work backwards from there to see when and where the erroneous stuff gets added.